# Where can I find a diagram of cortex connections?

Tags: neuroscience, brain

Has anyone come across a diagram (2D, 3D, maybe even interactive) of the connectiontions between cortex regions? Especially, the diagram should display the **strength** and **direction** of those connections (but not every single axon). I am interested in information like "Brodmann area 7 receives heavy connections from area 1,2,3 and 17,18", displayed in a neatly arranged way.

If there is no diagram that fulfills my need, is there another source of information, like a table, where I can find that sort of information?

Edit: After some more research I found this [paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2922151/) which contains some interesting diagrams in its appendix. However, this paper does not describe the human brain.

Comment: http://www.humanconnectomeproject.org/ might be a good point to start, I have not found a table of the sort you asked for, though.
I don't know whether this information was ever put together in the systematic way you are asking for. At least I never came across it in any of the lectures I've had or conferences I've gone to. For most contexts, it is not just important to know whether two brain areas are connected, but how exactly. Which cell types? Which cells exactly? etc. At this point, the information becomes too complex to be contained in one table. Thus: the connectome project.

Comment: Haha that's coool ! My new science project... Pickle brain in paraffin, then robotically slice it into micron thin slices which are imaged with an Epson Perfection scanner at 9600 DPI (2.6 microns).  write a simple computer program which can scan the data and compile a complete neural map of a brain in 3D space so that it can be viewed transparently by a computer in every dimension. every slice would take 3 minutes so that's 200 days to measure a human brain at 2 microns and 10 days for mouse brain. obviously it would not be in vivo.time to buy an epson and pickle a sheep.

Answer (score 1):

The Human Connectome Project looks at imaging the functional pathways in the brain and might include some answers to your question:

http://www.humanconnectomeproject.org

Here is an article in Nature about the project:

https://www.nature.com/articles/mp201792